# Is there a rule specifying which direction your card faces?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

With the introduction of Link cards, it makes a difference if some cards face you or face your opponent. Is there a rule that specifies that a card has to be played facing you?

Comment: I'd guess the state of the game has to be clear; if you're keeping the rest of your cards facing you, the relevant side of a multi-direction card should probably face you.

Comment: @Samthere not sure if you play yugioh but with the new addition about a month ago of a new mechanic (link summoning) it would be pretty game breaking if you could pick the cards orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even it is not a rule per se the game is created with the orientation in mind, as most cardgames i know of, that your cards are readable for you.
By turning the cards name to the bottom you would switch the game state as Link Arrows would point in different zones than intended.

While there is no rule in the rule book agaist it, there is a rule in the tournament floor rules (IV G. Game State)

http://www.yugioh-card.com/ygo_cms/ygo/all/uploads/KDE_TCG_Tournament_Policy_1_4.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Even though it's not said in the rule book, in all practicality, the card should be facing you. To minimize confusions and argument in as far as game play, it would be much more efficient to do so, and thus let the arrows point to where they're supposed to point at after this.

Comment: This does not add anything new to the question that has not been addressed by the existing answer